# Sharepoint 2010. Since I've installed the server there is always Error and I cannot open newly created site

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint-2010, correlation

I have server 2008, SQLServer 2012, Sharepoint 2010.

On the server the Roles are:
- Active directory domain services
- Application server
- DNS Server (no static IP set up)
- File Server
- Web Server (IIS)

Since I've installed the server there is always Error and I cannot open newly created site.

I will attach screenshots of this problem.

I read a lot of info in the web but there is no clear answer of what could cause this problem.

The site ask me for password which seems normal but after the prompt window the error comes.

**This is part of the ULS Viewer where I think is the problem:**

`*Exception occured while connecting to WCF endpoint: System.ServiceModel.ServerTooBusyException: The HTTP service located
 at http://win-5hc9j6ui0qb:32843/e4e149ff26c647479857e84773258768/ProfilePropertyService.svc is too busy.  ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (503) Server Unavailable.

 at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()

 at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)     -
 -- End of inner exception stack trace ---    Server stack trace:

 at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ProcessGetResponseWebException(WebException webException, HttpWebRequest request, HttpAbortReason abortReason)

 at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)

 at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)

 at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelFactory`1.SecurityRequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
 at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
 at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
 at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
 at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)    Exception rethrown
 at [0]:
 at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
 at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.IProfilePropertyService.GetProfileProperties()
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ProfilePropertyServiceClient.<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0(IProfilePropertyService channel)
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.MossClientBase`1.ExecuteOnChannel(String operationName, CodeBlock codeBlock)*`

I will appreciate any help here guys.

I was thinking to add some addons in IE?

Thanks in advance

[image: Error]

[image: Prompt window]

[image: Services]

[image: SQL]

[image: ULS Viewer]

Comment: Having the same issue, how did you fix it?

Answer (score -1):

I just solved a similar error.

ProfilePropertyService.svc is down!

Confirm `APPPOOL` for this service on `IIS`, it must be stopped. (It could be the service hung on start, but in this case your service print screen should state the service as Starting and that takes us to another error).

In my case Credentials were wrong on `APPPOOL`.

Or you may want to create a new APPPOOL and move all services to a new APPPOOL.

The account for this APPPOOL should be a domain account, if you have doubts on this account use FARM account for checking but then change it back to a service dedicated account as a good practice.